# Link ARM C and Rust

Tags: c, gcc, rust, compiler-errors, arm

I've been trying to get a C file to call a function from a Rust library for arm. To compile I tried:

```
cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/libmyLib.a -o main
```

I'm getting this error:

`error adding symbols: file in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

For some reason compiling for x86 and with regular gcc it runs and compiles normally.

Comment: This gives a diffrent error ```arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L. target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/libmylib.a main.c -o main``` ```undefined reference to `rust_function' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status``` This error is being caused by the external function being called which probably means these files aren't being linked properly.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? I am stuck at the same error and don't know where to investigate next.

Comment: No sorry I haven't gone back to this in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was compiling the Rust with `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` target (armv7) and the C with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` (armv6).

Use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.